# AngularJS Grouped select not populating

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope

I am having problems populating a grouped select box - I can't get the data into the select box.

I am trying to follow the following example as provided on http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select:

```
  Color grouped by shade:
  <select ng-model="color" ng-options="c.name group by c.shade for c in colors">
  </select><br/>
```

app.js

```
var messageApp = angular.module('messageApp',
    ['ngRoute', 'messageControllers', 'ngResource', 'messageServices', 'contactServices']);

messageControllers.controller('MessageComposeCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'Contact',
    function ($scope, $routeParams, Contact) {
        $scope.folder = 'Compose new message';

        $scope.contacts = Contact.query();
}]);

var contactServices = angular.module('contactServices', ['ngResource']);
contactServices.factory('Contact', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/v1/contacts/', {}, {
        query: { method: 'GET', isArray:false }
    });
}]);
```

My View

```
<h2><% folder %></h2>
<form role="form">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="to">Receiver *</label>
    <select ng-model="contacts" ng-options="c.name group by c.group for c in contacts">    
    </select>
</div>
```

Output

[image]

Baterang output showing that the contacts are being pulled in:

[image]

So I am in the correct scope as `<% folder %>` is populating correctly. So there is something that I am doing wrong in the population of the select box in the view...

```
<select ng-model="contacts" ng-options="c.name group by c.group for c in contacts">    
</select>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contacts is an object so you need to use the comprehension expression for object data sources:

```
ng-options="c.name group by c.group for (key,c) in contacts"
```

See angular docs for [select](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select).